# Can't add Dagger 2 dependency to java module

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, java-module

I'm trying to separate my android application into several modules. For instance I want to have 2 extra modules - Core and ViewModels. Both of them are pure java modules. However I'm having troubles when adding Dagger 2 dependencies to those java modules. Here's the build gradle file of one of the modules

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

However, when I sync the gradle I get the following error

```
Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Open File
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: I thought `android-apt` is deprecated in Android Studio 3.0+?

Comment: Yes exactly :) however it's still valid in java, I'll post the answer now, I've resolved the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've resolved the issue. Here's what my final `build.gradle` of the custom module looks like

```
plugins {
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.15"
}
apply plugin: 'java-library'



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

Dagger 2 successfuly generated necessary code and app worked like magic.